# Missing nemo right-click "extract/compress files"

Tags: 14.04, nemo, file-roller

recently I installed nemo as default filemanager replacing the nautilus. So far it work perfectly except the fact that I missed the "right click extract/compress". I've installed nemo 2.2.2 and nemo-fileroller through apt-get command on Ubuntu 14.04.

How can I have the right click menu for to "extract/compress"?

Comment: Is it possible to indicate exceptions in extensions and mimetypes? So, in other file managers, in a compressed file you don't see the contextual menu: "compress".

Answer (score 35):

Very simply, all you should need to do is install the [`nemo-fileroller`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nemo-fileroller) package:

```
sudo apt-get install nemo-fileroller
```

To apply the changes quit the file-manager with

```
nemo -q
```

to then (re-)start it like you normally would.

Comment: Dammit wish i would have saw this before the other thing now i don't know which works better

Comment: I have tried doing it this way, but it just didn't work.... I even tried it on multiple Ubuntu installs

Comment: It works, you have to restart file manager though:  `nemo -q`

Comment: I tired that and didn't work, but the action files did.

Comment: It's work for me

Comment: Simpler solution and works great

Answer (score 18):

Okay, I've tried lots of "solutions" but none of them work, so I went and dug out how things work, and here's how I did it on Ubuntu 14.04 and Nemo 2.2.2...

1. Open up terminal and type `cd ~/.local/share/nemo/actions/`
2. Create a new file/action for Compress by typing `nano compress.nemo_action`
3. Paste this contents into newly created file

   ```
   [Nemo Action]
   Active=true
   Name=Compress...
   Comment=compress %N
   Exec=file-roller -d %F
   Icon-Name=gnome-mime-application-x-compress
   Selection=Any
   Extensions=any;
   ```
4. Save the file and exit (CTRL+X, and just Enter)
5. Create a new file/action for "Extract here" by typing `nano extracthere.nemo_action`
6. Paste this contents into newly created file

   ```
   [Nemo Action]
   Active=true
   Name=Extract here
   Comment=Extract here
   Exec=file-roller -h %F
   Icon-Name=gnome-mime-application-x-compress
    #Stock-Id=gtk-cdrom
   Selection=Any
   Extensions=zip;7z;ar;cbz;cpio;exe;iso;jar;tar;tar;7z;tar.Z;tar.bz2;tar.gz;tar.lz;tar.lzma;tar.xz;
   ```
7. Save the file and exit (CTRL+X, and just Enter)
8. You're done. If you still don't have Compress/Extract here options in `Nemo`, just restart or log out/in.

Creating `Nemo` actions is the only way I've achieved this, I've tried several repos and tutorial of which none worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Just a note: since I wanted to apply the changes system.-wide, I put the new action files in /usr/local/share/nemo/actions instead of .local/...

Comment: In case someone else stumbles here that does not use Ubuntu, it worked also on rhel7 with Nemo 2.8.7

Comment: EDIT: to apply the changes system.-wide, I put the new action files in /usr/share/nemo/actions instead of .local/..

Answer (score 8):

To improve the Compress/Extract integration, I'm posting an Escape-Safe way (because folders with spaces in the name was crashing my file-roller):

Create the following `.nemo_action` files and their contents, at `/usr/share/nemo/actions`:

*compress.nemo_action*:

```
[Nemo Action]
Active=true
Name=Compress...
Comment=Compress "%f"
Exec=file-roller --add %F --default-dir=%P
Icon-Name=gnome-mime-application-x-compress
Selection=notnone
Extensions=any;
Quote=double
```

*extract-here.nemo_action*:

```
[Nemo Action]
Active=true
Name=Extract here
Comment=Extract "%f" here
Exec=file-roller --extract-here %F
Icon-Name=gnome-mime-application-x-compress
Selection=notnone
Extensions=zip;7z;ar;cbz;cpio;exe;iso;jar;tar;tar.Z;tar.bz2;tar.gz;tar.lz;tar.lzma;tar.xz;
Quote=double
```

*extract-to.nemo_action*:

```
[Nemo Action]
Active=true
Name=Extract to...
Comment=Extract to a folder of your choice.
Exec=file-roller --extract %F
Icon-Name=gnome-mime-application-x-compress
Selection=notnone
Extensions=zip;7z;ar;cbz;cpio;exe;iso;jar;tar;tar.Z;tar.bz2;tar.gz;tar.lz;tar.lzma;tar.xz;
Quote=double
```

Comment: If I put EscapeSpaces=true and Quote=double at the same time it won't work, Quote=double is enough to escape the spaces.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the above nemo actions is missing the "Quote=double" parameter otherwise files/directories that have space(s) in their name won't work.
e.g.

```
[Nemo Action]
Active=true
Name=Compress...
Comment=compress %N
Exec=file-roller -d %F
Icon-Name=gnome-mime-application-x-compress
Selection=any
Extensions=any;
Quote=double
```

Also useful is an "Extract to..." action, which allows you to select a different path where you may want to extract the files to.

e.g.
extractto.nemo_action

```
[Nemo Action]
Active=true
Name=Extract to...
Comment=Extract to...
Exec=file-roller -f %F
Icon-Name=gnome-mime-application-x-compress
#Stock-Id=gtk-cdrom
Selection=any
Extensions=zip;7z;ar;cbz;cpio;exe;iso;jar;tar;tar;7z;tar.Z;tar.bz2;tar.gz;tar.lz;tar.lzma;tar.xz;
Quote=double
```